# How Do I Calculate The Difference of Each Element in A List (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to Python and I wanted to know that how can I subtract All the Elements in A List in Python
For Eg -

```
list [5,6,7,8,9]
```

I want to subtract it like this = 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `reduce`, which expands out to subtracting all elements.

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x - y, [5,6,7,8,9])
-25
```

Answer (score 0):

To subtract each number from the first one, you can subtract the sum of them:

```py
>>> mylist = [5,6,7,8,9]
>>> print(mylist[0] - sum(mylist[1:]))
-25
```